# WebSphere Issue

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, websphere, action-mapping

I working in an Java application. I am using Struts2 and Hibernate. The application was working fine in Tomcat7 , But when I deployed that On IBM"S Websphere I am getting the following error for the following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/MYAPPS
```

```
Error 404: There is no Action mapped for action name . 

http://localhost:8080/MYAPPS/

Error 404: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path
```

Comment: Does it work if you put a final slash: `localhost:8080/MYAPPS/` ? Also ensure that the port is the right one as suggested by @Andres's answer

Comment: What version of the IBM Websphere?

Answer (score 1):

The default port is 9080. Change the port in url as others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Login to the console , click on servers -> serverName -> ports -> WC_defaulthost (webcontainer port )
   For example if it shows as 9080
2. Click on Environment -> Virtual Host -> default host (or the host the application is mapped to)- > Click on  Host Aliases . Make sure the port is defined, if not add the port and the restart the server.
3. access the application as follow.
   `http://localhost:9080/MYAPPS/`
   `http://hostname:9080/MYAPPS/`

If the problem persists, open the systemout.log file and look for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help to find the port number for web host or secure web host,
Go for the following path,
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01_demo/config/cells/localhostCell01/nodes/Dmgr_node,
try find this file serverindex.xml,
 there you can find the "WC_adminhost" port number.

Hope this help !
thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the virtual host issue. You obviously have configured it right as there's no virtualhost error.

What's your WAS's version? WAS V6.1.X has the notorious reputation not to support whatever is popular. Try adding this as a customized web container property:

- `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility`
  set its value to `true`